# RestKit: Distinct API for 2 entities that have a relationship

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

Entity 1 has foreign key to Entity 2. To fetch both, 2 APIs need to be triggered.

```
http://api1...
```

JSON:

```
Entity 1 : {
    property1 : value1,
    property1 : value1,
    foreighKeyToEntity2: value3
}
```

To fetch the second entity

```
http://api2/.../propertyA=value3
```

JSON:

```
Entity 2 : {
    propertyA : value1, (wich equesls to foreighKeyToEntity2 of Entity1)
    propertyB : valueA,
    propertyC : valueB,
}
```

Both entities have Core Data representation with 1:1 relationship. But how do I fetch the data from the server using restKit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using Multiple Base URLs (and Multiple Object Managers)](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1816)